# Исправить вопрос, поменяв только метку

Tags: поддержка, метки, предлагаемые-правки

Вот вопрос: [Ошибка времени выполнения: Входная строка имела неверный формат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/671625/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%92%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82/754476#754476). В качестве метки использовано только слово "pascal". Однако, вопрос касается "pascalABC.net", что и вызвало комментарий "о странном паскале". Попытка исправить вопрос, добавив только новую метку "pascalABC.net", ничего не дала: движок требует минимальных изменений в 6 символов. Добавление пробелов ничего не дает. Да, можно изменить вопрос добавлением чего-то другого, но это уже отсебятина.
Как быть?

Comment: нужно быстрее набирать 2000 репутации

Comment: Понятно, права модератора позволяют это. В описании привилегии, кстати, это явно не отражено.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov не права модератора, а привилегия [Правка вопросов и ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit). Там вроде бы явно написано.

Comment: Увы, явно не написано. По ссылке есть такая фраза "мы доверяем вам право редактировать в системе все, что угодно, и эти правки не будет попадать на проверку". Но воспринимается это скорее как упор на отсутствии проверки, а не на отсутствии стандартного ограничения.

Comment: Раньше в предлагаемых правках можно было изменять только метки, вот, например, [такая правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/176027). Наверно разработчики что-то сломали.

Comment: @diraria там две метки, возможно это в сумме даёт более "6 символов".

Comment: Раньше было так, что только правка метки (не трогая сообщение) проходила, а правка метки + правка одной буквы в сообщении не проходила. Так что они сломали уже сломанное.

Comment: @VadimTagil скажите, пожалуйста, а вы точно при редактировании изменяли только метки? И на другом вопросе это воспроизводится?

Comment: @diraria да, вот: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/187393 Сейчас у меня достаточно репутации для редактирования без ограничений, поэтому не могу проверить.

Comment: @VadimTagil ой, я перепутал, на самом деле я хотел написать автору вопроса. Но спасибо)

Comment: @ViktorTomilov скажите, пожалуйста, а вы точно при редактировании изменяли только метки? И на другом вопросе это воспроизводится?

Comment: @diraria Да, только метки.  А как вы предлагает вопроизводить на другом вопросе? Насильно куда-то впихнуть левую метку?

Comment: @ViktorTomilov да, предлагаю впихнуть левую метку в какой-нибудь вопрос, который вряд ли кому-нибудь пригодится. Например можно попробовать предложить правку с аналогичной заменой меток в [каком-нибудь заминусованном вопросе с меткой pascal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascal?page=33&sort=votes&pagesize=15) (потом если что можно обратно откатить).

Comment: @diraria Сейчас получается. Как итог: я напакостил. Но в первый раз я пытался менять только метки. Собственно, и потом в том же вопросе после правки Grundy (он заменил pascal на pascalABC.net, а нужно было добавить) мне пришлось, когда я добавлял вторую метку поместить  строку <!-- Комментарий для обхода ограничения в 6 символов -->, чтобы движок позволил внести изменения.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov спасибо что попробовали. Странно очень, что в первый раз не получалось, а сейчас получается. Было бы здорово, если бы удалось воспроизвести

Comment: @diraria нет, не получается повторить снова :( Красным сейчас выделяет только "кратко опишите смысл изменений", а в первый раз было еще и про 6 символов. Может, что-то уже поменяли в движке?